# Linux mintのc言語の開発環境について

Tags: linux, c

今日、Linux mintをダウンロードし、c言語の開発環境を整えたいと思っているのですがどうしたらいいのかわかりません
どなたか解決方法を教えてください

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　Linux Mint が動いているという前提で回答を書いてしまいましたが、もしまだ Linux Mint を立ち上げることに成功していない場合は、その旨コメント下さい。

Answer (score 5):

※ これは、Linux Mint を立ち上げられた上で、どのようにC言語の開発環境を整えるかについて解説した回答です。

### どうやってソフトウェアをインストールするか

Linux Mint で新しいソフトウェアをインストールするには、Software Manager を使う方法と、Synaptic または `apt` コマンドを使う方法があります。
Sofware Manager と Synaptic は、Linux Mint のメニューから選択することで起動できます。`apt` は、ターミナルの上でコマンドを打つことで利用できます。
詳しくは [Linux Mint のユーザーガイド](https://www.linuxmint.com/documentation.php) の「ソフトウェアの管理」→「ソフトウェアマネージャー」のあたりを見てください。

### どんなソフトウェアをインストールするか

C言語で書いたプログラムを動かすには、最低限、C言語のためのコンパイラが必要です。
しかし、Linux Mint には標準で `gcc` というコンパイラがインストールされているため、自分で新しくインストールする必要はありません。
ターミナルで行う CLI 操作に慣れているなら、プログラムが保存されたファイルを `gcc` に与えることで実行ファイルを作ることができます。

プログラムを書くためのエディタも好みのものをインストールしたい場合は、自分で選び、Software Manager か Synaptic / APT を使ってインストールすることになります。
GUI 環境で動くエディタが良いのでしたら gedit、VS Code、Atom、Sublime Text、Emacs などがあり、CLI 環境で動くエディタが良いのでしたら Vim、Emacs、Nano などがあります。
それぞれのエディタの公式ホームページに、「Debian / Ubuntu系でのインストール方法」としてインストールの仕方が載っていることが多いので、そちらも参考にしてみてください。
(個別のエディタのインストール方法が分からない場合は、また別に質問してください。)

Visual Studio のような、コンパイラとエディタ、デバッガーなどがひとまとめになっている「統合開発環境 (IDE)」をインストールしたいならば、それも自分で好みのものを選んでインストールすることになります。
上で挙げたエディタを IDE のように使うこともできますし、Eclipse、Geany、IntelliJ IDEAなどをインストールして使うこともできます。